# Query inside IntentService not getting executed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent, facebook-fql

I am executing a simple query(fql) inside IntentService (which is getting started with a button click) . Here is my onHandleIntent() method of the service class :

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Global appState = ((Global)getApplicationContext());
    System.out.println("inside the service now");   
    String uid=appState.uid[0];
    System.out.println("uid ="+uid);

    String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, online_presence, status FROM user WHERE uid="+uid+" ";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    System.out.println(session);
        Request request = new Request(session,                                  // starting of innerclass
        "/fql",                         
         params,                         
         HttpMethod.GET,                 
         new Request.Callback(){  

         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
              //Log.i(TAG, "Result: " +response.toString() );                        //response.toString()
         GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
            // String s = textViewResults.getText().toString();
          if (graphObject != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                       try {
                         JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {                     // always array.length()=1, loop will run jst 1 time
                             JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(j);
                                System.out.println("inside inner class now");
                                 System.out.println("id = " +object.get("uid").toString() );
                                 System.out.println("name = "+object.get("name").toString());
                                 System.out.println("op ="+object.get("online_presence").toString()+"niraj");
                                 name=object.get("name").toString();
                             }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {

                  e.printStackTrace();
                 }
          }          // end of if block


              }  // end of onCompleted method                  
      }); 

         // Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);//sleep for 1000 ms
  Request.executeBatchAsync(request); 


  System.out.println("outsise the inner class ____ name : "+name); 

}
```

the problem is that the code segment inside inner class (starting from Request) is not getting executed only . For the above code i am getting following output :

```
07-26 17:21:09.105: I/System.out(1541): inside the service now
07-26 17:21:09.105: I/System.out(1541): uid =100002621905500
07-26 17:21:09.136: I/System.out(1541): {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken    
token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[user_likes, user_status,    
friends_online_presence, user_online_presence]}, appId:"my app id"}
07-26 17:21:09.206: I/System.out(1541): outsise the inner class ____ name : null
```

I am not getting wat the error is . even log is not showing any error .please do help .

Comment: As I can see you are only passing a string as a parameter and doing nothing with it, where is it supposed to be executed?

Comment: but the same code when i run in my MainActivity works fine @zozelfelfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell, because I don't see the definition of the type Request, but I *suspect* you're having problems because you're expecting a callback in your IntentService. That won't work. An IntentService runs until all of the code in onHandleIntent() is complete, then it is destroyed. If something tries to make a callback, it won't work, because it can't find the instance.

You may need to use a started Service instead.

Comment: Thanks a lottt  @Joe Malin !! Using Service instead of IntentService worked .

Comment: just out of curiosity , can't we wait(sleep) inside IntentService for the callback .

Answer (score 0):

using
     Request.executeBatchAndWait(request);
in-place of
      Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

solves the problem as the "Request.executeBatchAndWait(request)" does't requires a callback , it receives the request and processes it in the same thread while the "Request.executeBatchAsync(request)" processes the  request result in a different thread , so in-order to process the result or determine whether the process succeded or failed a callback is specified .